# error as There are two properties named "userName" in XMLRootElement

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I have a class as

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Helloworld")
@XmlType(propOrder = { "userName"})
public class UserDetails {
    //User Name
    @XmlElement(name="UserName")
    private String userName;


    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

}
```

I am getting run time exception as

```
There are two properties named "userName" ...
```

Can any tell the mistake in above class.

Comment: It is because you have getter and setter and annotation on the field.

Comment: Thank you. can you tell me how to remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you have getter and setter and annotation on the field. You could fix it by moving annotation from field property to getter method.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Helloworld")
@XmlType(propOrder = { "userName"})
public class UserDetails {
    //User Name
    private String userName;

    @XmlElement(name="UserName")   
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
}
```